# How can I rewrite an anonymous Java class into a non-anonymous class?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Learning about anonymous classes and have this from Oracle.  I am hoping someone can show me what this would look like if I did not use anonymous classes.  How would I have done this with a new class?

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> In this example, the method invocation btn.setOnAction specifies what happens when you select the Say 'Hello World' button. This method requires an object of type EventHandler. The EventHandler interface contains only one method, handle. **Instead of implementing this method with a new class**, the example instead uses an anonymous class expression. Notice that this expression is the argument passed to the btn.setOnAction method.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Consider the difference and similarities between a normal top level class and an anonymous class.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't know what to do.

Comment: really... just create a new class implements EventHandler<ActionsEvent>, I don't see the problem sorry

Comment: In my IDE, I hit `F6` for move and it suggests a name.  It doesn't need to be harder than that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "non-anonymous class"? The closest thing to an anonymous class would be a named local class (local = inside a method); it takes the least effort to convert it to that. Then, you could also have a non-local inner class, i.e. a class that is an inner class, but is not inside a method. It takes slightly more effort to convert to that. Finally, you have a static inner class or full-fledged top-level class; it takes the most effort to convert to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a new non-anonymous class somewhere. I did it as a nested class inside `HelloWorld`:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new MyEventHandler());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class MyEventHandler implements EvenHandler<ActionEven>
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you don't have to put the MyEventHandler class in another file?  Or if you did would you just use import?

Comment: No, that is not neccesary. You can do it if you want to. I chose to make a nested class file, to keep the answer short.

Answer (score 1):

The `EventHandler` class is stateless, so all the instances of this class are functionally equivalent. We just need one single instance of this class to perform the `handle` operation because the functionality of this method depends only on the parameter passed to it, it does not depend on the state of the object as it does not have any.Thus, it should be a singleton. Using Anonymous classes will create a new instance every time a call to `setOnAction` is executed. To avoid this, you can consider storing an instance of the `EvenHandler` implementation in a private static final field and reusing it by using static factory method as below:

```
public class HandlerProvider{
private static final EvenHandler<ActionEvent> EVENT_HANDLER=new ActionEventHandler();

public static EvenHandler<ActionEvent> getEventHandler(){
return EVENT_HANDLER;
}
private static class ActionEventHandler implements EvenHandler<ActionEvent>
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            //your action goes here
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you can avoid unnecessary object creation on each method call.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what to do.

1. Create a new class that implements the desired interface.<sup>1</sup>
2. Move the code from the anonymous class to the new class.
3. Wherever your anonymous class was used, change it by a new instance of this class.

Applying this to the provided example:

```
class FooEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    //...
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //...
        btn.setOnAction(new FooEventHandler());
        //...
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup>: Note that the class that implements the interface will follow the rules of any simple class you write, this means it can be a top level class, an inner class or a `static` *inner* class.